# Import Array of JSON Data into spread JS

Tags: javascript, spreadjs

I am trying to import an array of object into spreadjs, I am using the *fromJSON* method but it doesnt get imported, my data is an array of object that looks like this

```
let jsonObj = 
 [{ 'name' : 'One',
   'id': 1,
   'colour': 'blue'
 },
 { 'name' : 'Two',
   'id': 2,
   'colour': 'yellow'
 },
 { 'name' : 'Three',
   'id': 3,
   'colour': 'red'
 }]
```

I am currently doing `sheet.fromJSON(jsonObj)`

Comment: It doesn't look like your data matches [the schema](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/jsonschema.html?highlight=json%2C) that SpreadJS uses.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for using GrapeCity SpreadJS -  fromJSON method is used to load a complete spreadsheet file based on our SSJSON file format.   However, to load an array you can use [setBindingPath](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/SpreadJS%7EGC.Spread.Sheets.Worksheet%7EsetBindingPath.html) and [setDataSource](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/v14/online/SpreadJS%7EGC.Spread.Sheets.Worksheet%7EsetDataSource.html) methods to bind cells to your object properties and then bind the array.

here is an [example](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/features/data-binding/sheet-level-binding/purejs)